# jsf 2.0 bean extends another bean Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null

Tags: java, jsf-2, managed-bean

```
public class SuperUser extends User implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String username;

  private String pin;

 //getters and setters
 }
```

when I use this in a managed bean and try to access it in the facelets file like this

```
<h:inputText id="firstName" value="#{userManager.superUser.firstName}" required="true" maxlength="30" size="30"/>
```

I get an exception

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /superUser/create.xhtml @18,96 value="#{userManager.superUser.firstName}": Target Unreachable
```

Does that mean the you cannot extend java beans if you want to access their properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that `#{userManager.superUser}` returned `null` and hence `setFirstName()` cannot be called on it. JSF won't create nested object properties for you. You have to do it yourself.

To fix this, just ensure inside the backing bean class behind `#{userManager}` that it's not null. E.g.

```
private SuperUser superUser = new SuperUser();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the method `getFirstName()` inside User class public?

Similarly, is `getSuperUser()` of the userManager managed bean public?